# Is navigation to another page in angular introjs possible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intro.js

I am using [angular introjs](https://github.com/mendhak/angular-intro.js/) in my project on a page for the first time. It works fine and I am able to use customized options too. But want to navigate to another page through the steps.

For example, on first step I click next, the second step should be navigation to another page, and not the step in the same page.

Is there an option under `ng-intro-options` in angular introjs for navigating to other pages aswell?

Comment: You could go ahead and learn about `ngRoute` or the `ui-router`.Both are pretty simple!

Comment: Hi @SatejS , thanks. But I used ngRoute and ui-router. I want to know if there is some option as a part of ng-intro-options. I mean don't want to route outside the tour.

Comment: I'm the author of Intro.js. I'm not sure about the Angular.js binding but in the examples folder you can find a `multi-page` example that does what you want.

Comment: Oh!! Thanks a lot! I will check @AfshinMehrabani